React Native 0.73 - how to debug network and redux?
I am a bit lost. I can't find anything that would help me debug vanilla react-native (no expo) and being able to see the network (I want to see all API calls that are made from my app) and the Redux state.
So far I have tried few thins which didn't work because are either still in development or already deprecated... or the documentation doesn't cover that case (or I'm not good in searching). So far this includes:

react-devtools (Works only for structure of components and their state)
JS  debugger - context menu from the app with d or j - I see the console, source and memory tab - not helpful
React Native Debugger - ⚠️ This app is currently only supported old Remote Debugger, if you're looking for new debugger support (e.g. Hermes / JSI / New Architecture) of React Native Debugger
Redux DevTools - I don't see a way I can use this, but seems to be the standard for debugging Redux
Ractotron - I've tried the connection with Redux but failed (to be fair I didn't spent much time on this), the network functionality is just dumping the response that I can see with console.log

I've read and tested the debugging solutions from the official documentation but it is not covering the use cases I need.
Am I missing something or I'm just not doing the things right to make any of these tools to work properly?
PS: I've checked this one, but the thing that was working is for Expo 49

When you say ...already deprecated, are you talking about Flipper? You can give it a try if you're still on 0.73.x. I have a production app that's running on 0.73.6 and I use Flipper to debug Redux logic for it.

I haven't tried it because of that deprecation notice, I will give it a try. Thanks.

PS: I confirm Flipper works. Thanks again!
